# Compare 2 array of jsons and form a array from that?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays named

```
a = [{"id":"1","mark":"96",...},{"id":"2","mark":"65",...}];

b = [{"student_id":"1","grade":"A"},{"student_id":"2","grade":"c"}];
```

I want to compare 2 arrays and if **'id'** and **'student_id'** **matches** i want to push the grade value to the 'a' array . Then my result will be like:

**Expected Result:**

```
c = [{"id":"1","mark":"96","grade":"A",...},
    {"id":"2","mark":"65","grade":"c".....}];
```

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: Please add your try and we can discuss about your problem.

Comment: why this much down votes.it's a valid question , right? I had a try and i got the result by using the for loop, posting it here makes the question much more complicated. That's why i avoided that

Comment: actually it looks like, write the code for me. but with your rep, you shold know, how SO works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can do it in `n` complexity:

```js
const a = [{
  "id": "1",
  "mark": "96"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "mark": "65"
}];

const b = [{
  "student_id": "1",
  "grade": "A"
}, {
  "student_id": "2",
  "grade": "c"
}];

let map = a.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.id] = item;
  return acc;
}, {});

b.forEach(item => {
  if (map[item.student_id]) {
    map[item.student_id].grades = item.grade;
  }
});

console.log(Object.values(map));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.find` to identify the matching element in the other array, and `.reduce` to make a new object out of it:

```js
const marks = [{"id":"1","mark":"96"},{"id":"2","mark":"65"}];
const students = [{"student_id":"1","grade":"A"},{"student_id":"2","grade":"c"}];

const result = marks.reduce((resultsSoFar, mark) => {
  const id = mark.id;
  const grade = students.find(({ student_id }) => student_id === id).grade;
  resultsSoFar.push({ ...mark, grade });
  return resultsSoFar;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following by using array's `map()` and `forEach()`:

```js
var a = [{"id":"1","mark":"96"},{"id":"2","mark":"65"}];

var b = [{"student_id":"1","grade":"A"},{"student_id":"2","grade":"c"}];

var c = a.map(function(i){
  b.forEach(function(j){
    if(i.id===j.student_id){
      i.grade = j.grade;
    }
  });
  return i;
})

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to loop over array `a` and array `b` then whenever you get a match in `id` and `student_id` value add the `grade` property and push the object in new array `c`. You can also `break` the for loop to avoid further unnecessary loop after the match is found.

```js
var a = [{"id":"1","mark":"96"},{"id":"2","mark":"65"}];
var b = [{"student_id":"1","grade":"A"},{"student_id":"2","grade":"c"}];
var c = [];

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
  var objA = a[i];
  for(var j=0; j<b.length; j++){
    var objB = b[j];
    if(objA.id === objB.student_id){
      objA.grade = objB.grade;
      c.push(objA);
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no `"grade"`-object inside array `a`:

```js
let a = [{"id": "1", "mark": "96"}, {"id": "2", "mark": "65"}];
let b = [{"student_id": "1", "grade": "A"}, {"student_id": "2", "grade": "c"}];
let c =[];

for(var iterateA = 0, elA; elA = a[iterateA]; iterateA++) {
 for(var iterateB = 0, elB; elB = b[iterateB]; iterateB++) {
  if(elA.id === elB.student_id) {
   elA['grade'] = elB.grade;
   c.push(elA);
  }
 }
}
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j<b.length;j++) {
            if(a[i].id === b[j].student_id) {
                c.push({
                    'id': a[i].id,
                    'mark': a[i].mark,
                    'grade': b[j].grade
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using map and find

```js
a = [{"id":"1","mark":"96"},{"id":"2","mark":"65"}];

b = [{"student_id":"1","grade":"A"},{"student_id":"2","grade":"c"}];

updatedA = a.map((val) => {
  let bVal = b.find((item) => item.student_id === val.id)
  if(bVal){
   val.grade = bVal.grade;
  }
  return val;
})

console.log(updatedA);
```